# How to display xml data as tabular format

Tags: sql-server, xquery

here is my xml which i want to show as tabular form

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

SELECT 
    x.y.value('(row/text())[1]', 'varchar(5)')
FROM @xml.nodes('root') x(y)
```

it is displaying only first rows.
i want to display data like

```
Mycolumn
-----------
one
two
three
```

please guide me what i need to change in my sql. thanks

i could not issue select into with xquery like the below way

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

SELECT *
INTO #Fields
FROM (SELECT 
    x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') as fields11
FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y))

SELECT * FROM #Fields
DROP TABLE #Fields
```

but i could use insert into with xuqery like below way

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

CREATE TABLE #Fields(Field varchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Fields
SELECT 
    x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)

SELECT * FROM #Fields
DROP TABLE #Fields
```

so anyone can help me to construct select into with xquery. thanks

### NOW Select into works with XQUERY

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

SELECT  x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') Mycolumn into #Fields
FROM    @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)

select * from #Fields
drop table #Fields
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT  x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') Mycolumn
FROM    @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)
```

Path in `nodes` method from which the rows are generated should be `root/row`, this way three rows will be generated and for each of the values in rows expression `text()[1]` should extract it's value.

Comment: thanks i have updated my question can u plzz have a look. thanks again for answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped. For `SELECT...INTO...FROM` you just have to add table alias. Last line of the failing query should be for instance: `FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)) tbl` where `tbl` is alias.